# Which version of qt is used on Blackberry 10.0 OS (momentics 1.0)?

Tags: qt, blackberry-10

I am curious about the qt version used on Blackberry 10 momemtics IDE. Can I use QT5 for blackberry 10 development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the documentation you can find [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Creator-with-BlackBerry-10).

> The current release of the BlackBerry 10 Gold NDK
>   [developer.blackberry.com] **includes Qt 4.8 for both the simulator
>   target (x86) and device targets (arm)** available for development.
>   Compared to the development for the PlayBook, Qt is integrated in the
>   BlackBerry 10 device firmware and so can be used by Qt applications as
>   shared libraries.

The page is quite detailed. Have a look at it.

However, Qt5 can still be considered. You can find more information on how to use this Qt version in [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5-on-BlackBerry10) other page, which states:

> Currently, Qt5 is neither included in the BlackBerry 10 device
>   software nor in the BlackBerry 10 SDK. However, **Qt5 on BlackBerry 10
>   has reached a excellent level of quality and can be used for
>   developing and publishing applications to BlackBerry World**.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry 10 supplies only Qt 4 libraries.

You can use Qt 5 as long as you bundle your application with self-built Qt libraries.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5-on-BlackBerry10) you can find detailed information.